# Sketchup: Hide all elements above a certain height

Tags: sketchup

I have just received an architectural plan of a home as a SketchUp file:

[image]

I would like to view the furniture and inner room settings in first floor, but the ceiling and second floor are hiding them.

I have tried removing the elements from the model (as can be seen in the furthest model), but it's tedious, and they can't be restored quickly.

**Is there a way to quickly hide all elements above a certain height (for example, 2 meters above the ground level)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the section tool to define a section plane.  Everything beyond the section cut will be visible and accessible.

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate with a step-by-step instructions?

Answer (score 2):

Really, this is a planning task. If you want to perform tasks like this you should assign them to distinctive layer collections.

Try creating a series of layers before you do any design work, giving them names that reflect their purpose.

Divide them into sets by giving them prefixes and suffixes.  For instance...

- outer_garden

  - outer_garden_plants
- outer_paving

---

- outer_wall

  - outer_wall_window
  - outer_wall_door

---

- inner_wall

  - inner_ground_wall

    - inner_ground_wall_fixture
- inner_ground_floor

  - inner_ground_floor_fixture
- inner_ground_ceiling

  - inner_ground_ceiling_fixture

...and so on.

Display of the layers can be turned on and off as needed then.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your walls as a component, and if you apply a section plane WITHIN the component, it will not impact other elements not within the component, allowing you to "turn on plan" and "turn off plan" at will.